# Mimecast requires our SPF to include all the Public IP addresses

Tags: spf

We are a small business using ISP Bellhosting to host our domain- Our major client just added MIMECAST who now requires we establish our SPF record in our DNS - We did that but our email are still blocked by Mimecast who now requires us to include in our SPF all Public IP addresses that Bellhosting is using via Memamailservers. Our ISP maintains we have 1 email IP address- How can we can we get the Megamailservers public IP addresses used to forward our emails. and include them in our SPF record

Comment: I would ask your mail provider for a complete list. They may even have an SPF record that you can include from your spf record ("v=spf1 include:spf.record.for.memamail.here")

Comment: Why not publish a wide-open SPF policy? "v=spf1 all"

Answer (score 4):

Normally you would ask your email provider if there is something to use in [the `include` mechanism](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#include), e.g. `TXT "v=spf1 include:mailservers.example.com -all"`.

However, this [Bellhosting](https://bellhosting.ca/) doesn't seem like an service provider who cares about this at all:

- Their website is just a login form: there's nothing informative. Then, this [megamailservers.com](http://megamailservers.com/) seems like a page that has been build around year 2000 and hasn't been updated ever since. Probably that's not their only service that hasn't been developed for a while...
- Bellhosting hasn't implemented SPF for their own domain. Neither has megamailservers.com.
- While it's possible to find some PDF Guides of their services from Google, there zero technical specifications of anything: they are brochures at best.

So I guess if you call their support they'd probably answer: "What's SPF?", and aren't going to implement DKIM and DMARC any time soon, either.

**STEP 1:** Short term. Figure correct SPF settings by yourself. It seems like megamailservers.com has three MX records. Wow, they are all on the same subnet, telling more about their quality.

```
megamailservers.com. IN  MX   10 mx1c1.megamailservers.com.  IN  A  69.49.103.242
megamailservers.com. IN  MX  100 mx2c1.megamailservers.com.  IN  A  69.49.103.243
megamailservers.com. IN  MX  150 mx3c1.megamailservers.com.  IN  A  69.49.103.244
```

Based on this + `PTR` records I'd say whole Megamail is probably within subnet `69.49.103.242/29`. At first I would suggest adding `TXT "v=spf1 ip4:69.49.103.242/29 ~all"` for this subnet.

**STEP 2:** Long term. Find a competent service provider that knows how to implement the current minimum requirements for professional email services: SPF, DKIM and DMARC. Use their own settings + at least one known customer as a reference.